# When installing via yum / dnf / apt winbind is missing

Tags: freeradius

I have tried installing freeradius 3.0 / 3.2 on almalinux 8.9 and 9.3 / rocky 9.3 linux as well as ubuntu 20.04. From both the default repos and the networkradius repos.

And in all cases the winbind in mods_available folder is missing? (In all cases i installed samba-winbind-client (sambawbclient)

Is the only way to get winbind when installing freeradius to manually compile?